# Rails has_one relationship safe resource.build_resource in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-one

I have a page that takes a user through a short sign up tutorial when they create their account in order to create their first resource.  In my app, :hotel belongs to :user, and :user has_one hotel.  For the tutorial page, in my controller, I have:

```
    @hotel = current_user.build_hotel
```

Which works, except that it a user somehow finds him back on the tutorial page that command disassociates their previously created hotel.  In other words, the second time the user accesses the page with:

```
 @hotel = current_user.build_hotel
```

The user_id field in the hotel they created the first time becomes nil.  Obviously that is a serious problem.  I can do a before_filter on that page, but I'm not very happy about having a way for the user to screw everything up simply by visiting a page.  How should I properly use the build command for a has_one relationship?

Comment: I an't see the issue, I guess you've a hidden field containing the user id. This one could be set with `current_user` directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test for the existence of a hotel before building it:

```
 @hotel = current_user.hotel || current_user.build_hotel
```